# Postgres SSL client certificate - database server CA failed to start

Tags: postgresql, ssl, client

I want to configure SSL so that clients can only require certificate signed by root CA `ca.crt`, then every client must use their issued e.g. cert **postgresql.crt**, key **postgresql.key** and **password** to connect to database server. Hereby allowing the database server to verify each client certificate on authentication.

Postgres v14 server configs:

**postgresql.conf**

```
...
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = ca.crt   # root CA or (root+intermediate CA bundle) that signed client cert.
#ssl_cert_file =
#ssl_key_file =
...
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
...
hostssl  all  all  all  md5  clientcert=verify-ca
...
```

Starting database server failed with this error.

```
...
FATAL: could not load server certificate file "server.crt": No such file or directory
...
```

Why does it fail, I've no need for **server.crt** and **server.key** because server should be doing the client verification using `ca.crt` not the client?

Reading postgres document doesn't help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the /full path/ to the crt file in postgresql.conf?

Comment: _I've no need for server.crt and server.key_ -- may be you don't, but the server certainly does.

Comment: While it may be possible to construct a system which uses client certs and makes server certs optional, that is not what has been done.  If you want to use SSL, you will need to have a server cert, even if you don't do anything interesting with it.

Comment: @PhillW. I try /full path/cat.crt but is still requesting ```server.crt``` on the start.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to provide the server certificate (by default `server.crt`) and the corresponding private key (default `server.key` **with restrictive permissions**) in the data directory, otherwise you cannot start with SSL support.

To verify the client certificate, you should use `md5 clientcert=verify-full` in `pg_hba.conf`. If you don't need that extra password, and the client certificate is enough for authentication, you could simply use certificate authentication:

```
hostssl  all  all  all  cert
```

Comment: While I provide ```server.crt``` and ```server.key``` on server side it start successful. psql failed to connect if I do not provide ```root.crt``` on the client side even after configuring ```clientcert=verify-full```, on providing ```root.crt``` with both ```postgresql.crt``` and ```postgresql.key``` I notice client cert was ignored and that's not good. Could that be a bug or something.

Comment: Not a bug, but your mistake. Either the common name in the server certificate is not correct, or you didn't specify `sslrootcert` correctly on the client side.

Comment: I don't want the same CN on both server side cert and all clients side cert. I want each client cert should use client postgres user name as their CN, but I'm facing an error on the server side CN because it doesn't match with each individual client CN. Postgres docs is great but in this use case is not clear on _Client Certificate Authentication_ setup. @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the support.

Comment: I cannot really follow that. But I gather that you understand the cause of the problem now?